# How to change numpy array int values to chars?

Tags: python

I am trying to change the value of a numpy array with generated values to char :

```
np_array = np.random.randint(0, 255, 5)
for i in range(256):
    np_array[sample_data == i] = chr(i)
```

However it gives me the error :

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '\x00'
```

I'd assume that np.array is flexible like a list able to hold other values is that not case? does it work like a real array? do I need to create another variable that is a char, how do I do that without having a loop?

Comment: You need to change the dtype of the array to `dtype('Object')`

Comment: Numpy arrays are more efficient, in terms of memory use, than Python lists. The trade off for that is that they can only hold one type. If you want a different type, you need to create a new array. You can also change the dtype to Object as Barmar suggested, but that is no more memory efficient than a regular Python list.

Comment: How do I go about creating a new array for this? sorry newbie at numpy here

Comment: Did you read the error message?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. 'I'd assume that np.array is flexible like a list able to hold other values is that not case?" No, this is not the case. It's not clear to me how someone decides to use Numpy without understanding that **the point** of Numpy is to store values of the same, usually numeric type, for efficiency reasons.

Comment: Also, please keep in mind that text and bytes are *different* things, and there generally isn't any particular reason to treat numeric values in the range 0...255 as representing characters. **Please** read https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/ and https://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain.html.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel: "It's not clear to me how someone decides to use Numpy without understanding that the point of Numpy is to store values of the same, usually numeric type, for efficiency reasons." - I think what usually happens is that the confused user *didn't* decide to use NumPy. Someone else did, like an instructor, or the Pandas devs, and the user ends up interacting with NumPy without really understanding the point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`numpy.ndarray.view`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.view.html) method to view the integers as unicode characters.

Note:
Since you are generating integers without specifying their `dtype` - it is selected automatically. It can be different on different systems, and you have to set it explicitly before calling `.view`:

```py
np_array = np_array.astype('uint32')
```

Alternatively, you can simply specify it when generating the integers, and then you won't need to change it in the future:

```
np_array = np.random.randint(0, 255, 5, dtype='uint32')
```

---

To convert integers to unicode characters you can use either 'U1': 4 bytes, or 'U2': 8 bytes.

Here I'm setting the necessary `dtype` just to be explicit:

```py
np_array = np_array.astype('uint32').view('U1')
# or
np_array = np_array.astype('uint64').view('U2')
```

Credit:
https://gist.github.com/tkf/2276773

Comment: There's also `S1` for `uint8`

Comment: The default integer dtype is whatever corresponds to C `long`, not necessarily int64. On Windows, it's int32.

Comment: @user2357112, thanks! Corrected my answer.